# mostrar un array de objetos que contienen array en Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs

necesito recorrer un array de objetos que contienen arrays en vue, pero a la hora de mostrarlos en una tabla no puedo acceder a cada uno de ellos, a penas estoy empezando en vue js y no sé como recorrerlo de esta forma

```
var App = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
            progresion: [
                {
                    c: ['C', 'Dm', 'Em', 'F', 'G', 'Am', 'Bdim'],
                    d: ['D', 'Em', 'F#m', 'G', 'A', 'Bm', 'C#dim'],
                    e: ['E', 'F#m', 'G#m', 'A', 'B', 'C#m', 'D#dim'],
                    f: ['F', 'Gm', 'Am', 'Bb', 'C', 'Dm', 'Edim'],
                    g: ['G', 'Am', 'Bm', 'C', 'D', 'Em', 'F#dim'],
                    a: ['A', 'Bm', 'C#m', 'D', 'E', 'F#m', 'G#dim'],
                    b: ['B', 'C#m', 'D#m', 'E', 'F#', 'G#m', 'A#dim'],
                },
                {
                    Cm: ['Cm','Ddim','Eb','Fm','Gm','Ab','Bb'],
                    Dm: ['Dm','Edim','F','Gm','Am','Bb','C'],
                    Em: ['Em','F#dim','G','Am','Bm','C','D'],
                    Fm: ['Fm','Gdim','Ab','Bbm','Cm','Db','Eb'],
                    Gm: ['Gm','Adim','Bb','Cm','Dm','Eb','F'],
                    Am: ['Am','Bdim','C','Dm','Em','F','G'],
                    Bm: ['Bm','C#dim','D','Em','F#m','G','A']
                }
            ]

    },
    methods:{
        console: function(){
            return console.log(this.progresion[0].c[0])
        }
    }
})
```

cuando lo ejecuto en la consola me sale bien, pero al intentar mostrarlo con el v-for me da un error
y no sé como hacer para que se muestre correctamente

```
                    <button @click="console" class="ui button">Console</button>
                    <table class="ui celled table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Nota Base</th>
                                <th>Menor</th>
                                <th>Menor</th>
                                <th>Mayor</th>
                                <th>Mayor</th>
                                <th>Menor</th>
                                <th>Disminuido</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr v-for="res in progresion">
                            <td>res[0].c[0]</td>
                            <td>24</td>
                            <td>Engineer</td>
                            <td>Engineer</td>
                            <td>Engineer</td>
                            <td>Engineer</td>
                            <td>Engineer</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
```

Comment: En primer lugar te hace faltan las llaves. `{{ }}` para imprimir el valor. Qué error está obteniendo ?

Comment: se las pongo y me dice TypeError: res[0] is undefined

Comment: y si lo dejo {{ res.c }} me sale el array completo: [ "C", "Dm", "Em", "F", "G", "Am", "Bdim" ]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado?

Comment: el mismo que cuando pongo: console.log(this.progresion[0].c[0]) el resultado es= C, que solo me salga la pocision 0 del array, no todo el array completo

Comment: Entiendo que en la primera fila de la tabla espera el resultado `C D E F G A B` y en la segunda fila `Cm Dm Em Fm Gm Am Bm`, si es así podría usar doble `v-for`

Comment: si, que en cada campo me salga un array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, hace falta las llaves para imprimir el valor en cada iteración.

Para iterar el primer array, bastaría con un `v-for`.

```
<tr v-for="res in progresion">
   <td>{{ res}}</td>
```

Pero si desea obtener el primer elemento de cada array, puede añadir otro `v-for`, e imprimir el primer elemento con la posición `0`

```
<tr v-for="res in progresion">
   <td>
      <span v-for="item in res">{{ item[0]}}</span>
   </td>
```

Comment: gracias, me sirvió